# Unity - playerprefs deletes info

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a game. it has a login panel and rememmer me button. i keep the info on regedit. when I click rememmer me button it works and when I start game after click button it gets my info like id and pass but when I start again it deletes my id and pass on regedit. So it get just one time. I couldn't find the problem or fix way. Can you help me? Thank you.
Here is my codes:

```
void Start()
{
        if(PlayerPrefs.GetInt("BeniHatirla")==1)
        {
           

            Debug.Log("start "+PlayerPrefs.GetInt("BeniHatirla"));
            BeniHatirlaGetir();
        }
        
}
```

Here is the method ı called in start:

```
public void BeniHatirlaGetir()
{
    isim = PlayerPrefs.GetString("BeniHatirlaIsim");
    sifre = PlayerPrefs.GetString("BeniHatirlaSifre");
    Debug.Log("kullanici "+isim+sifre);
    BeniHatirlaUniSlider.value = 1;
    Debug.Log("Ogrenm Durumu"+PlayerPrefs.GetInt("OgrenimDurumuBelirleme"));
    switch (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("OgrenimDurumuBelirleme"))
    {
        case 1:
            OrtaOkulKadiTextBox.text = isim.ToString();
            OrtaokulKsifreTextBox.text = sifre.ToString();
            LoginPanelleri[0].SetActive(true);
            break;
        case 2:
            LiseKadiTextBox.text = isim.ToString();
            LiseKsifreTextBox.text = sifre.ToString();
            LoginPanelleri[1].SetActive(true);
            break;
        case 3:
            UniversiteKadiTextBox.text = isim.ToString();
            UniversiteKsifreTextBox.text = sifre.ToString();
            LoginPanelleri[2].SetActive(true);
            break;
    }
}
```

And here is the rememmer me button:

```
public void BeniHatırlaButon()
{     
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("BeniHatirla", 1);
        switch (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("OgrenimDurumuBelirleme"))
        {
            case 1:
                PlayerPrefs.SetString("BeniHatirlaIsim", OrtaOkulKadiTextBox.text.ToString());
                PlayerPrefs.SetString("BeniHatirlaSifre", OrtaokulKsifreTextBox.text.ToString());
                break;
            case 2:
                PlayerPrefs.SetString("BeniHatirlaIsim", LiseKadiTextBox.text.ToString());
                PlayerPrefs.SetString("BeniHatirlaSifre", LiseKsifreTextBox.text.ToString());
                break;
            case 3:
                PlayerPrefs.SetString("BeniHatirlaIsim", UniversiteKadiTextBox.text.ToString());
                PlayerPrefs.SetString("BeniHatirlaSifre", UniversiteKsifreTextBox.text.ToString());
                break;
        }
    
   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're running some debugger, it may be missing out on when it actually saves the values to disk. From the documentation for `PlayerPrefs`:

> By default Unity writes preferences to disk during OnApplicationQuit(). In cases when the game crashes or otherwise prematuraly exits, you might want to write the PlayerPrefs at sensible 'checkpoints' in your game. This function will write to disk potentially causing a small hiccup, therefore it is not recommended to call during actual gameplay.

So if you are exiting the application prematurely through debugging it may be that you just need to call `PlayerPrefs.Save()` right after you try to write the values.